# How do I use Linq Sum After grouping by

Tags: c#

I have a list of records i.e.

```
Id, Activity, Marks
1, A, 12
1, B, 14
1, B, 15
2, A, 1
2,A,100
```

I want to group the records by Id and Activity and then return the sum of the records.

How do I achieve that using LINQ? E.g. result should be:

```
Id, Activity, TotalMarks
1, A, 12
1, B, 29
2, A, 101
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<Activity> activity;
activity
  .GroupBy (a => new {a.Id, a.Activity})
  .Select (ag => new {ag.Key.Id, ag.Key.Activity, TotalMarks=ag.Select(a => a.Marks).Sum()})
```

Comment: I now get a new collection with Id, Actvity and TotalMarks as properties. How do I cast it to List<T> where T is a class with the three properties Id, Activity and TotalTrades

Comment: You can use `.Select(...)` and `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 
    (from x in values
    group x by new {x.Id, x.Activity} into g
    select new MyClass()
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        Activity = g.Key.Activity,
        TotalMarks = g.Sum(y => y.Marks)
    }).ToList();
```

Where `MyClass` has the properties specified.